# Symfony Form Type with multiple input fields

Tags: forms, symfony-2.1, custom-field-type

With Symfony 2.1, how can I create a form type with multiple input fields in it?
So in the form builder I want to add a custom form type :

```
$builder->add('test','my_fieldtype')
```

Then if I do this in the template :

```
{{ form_row(form.test) }}
```

I want it to display a row that has a label and 2 or 3 input fields. Something like the date type I suppose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to create a [custom field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html). The best way to achieve it is to look at the code of the [DateTimeType](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Core/Type/DateTimeType.php).

Remember to create as well the appropriate Twig form template.

Comment: Hi thx for the answer, i was looking in that direction, just had problems with the multiple fields in one field type.
in the end it seems like i was missing a DataTransformer to make it work. thx !

Comment: Thanks Roberto for pointing to the DateTimeType asn an example.